# Conditional handling Firebase push notifications

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that supports Android and iPhone. The app sends and receives push notifications using Firebase for Android and Azure Notification Hub for iOS. If the app sends a notification from the sender's phone, multiple people in the group receive it and can handle it. But it is not what we need. I want only the first receiver to handle the notification, and the others should ignore it. Is there a good way to implement it?

Here is my code that handles push notifications on Android:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnMessageReceived(message);

            string messageBody = message.GetNotification()?.Body;

            VideoCallMessage videoCallMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoCallMessage>(messageBody);

            if (App.UserContext.IsEmployee)
            {
                // convert the incoming message to a local notification
                SendLocalNotification(messageBody);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Debug("FirebaseService.OnMessageReceived()", $"Exception in OnMessageReceived(). ErrorMessage: {ex.Message}, Stack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");

            Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes.TrackError(ex); // Report the exception to App Center
        }
    }
```

For iOS in Delegate.cs:

```
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler();

        NSDictionary userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;
        ProcessNotification(userInfo);
    }

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);

        NSDictionary userInfo = notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;
        ProcessNotification(userInfo);
    }
```

Comment: After someone handle the notification, it need to send the feedback. As i know, the firebase do not provide the service to do that. You need to make it by your own.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Thank you for your comment. May I ask this: If the first receiver sends the feedback, how will it help others not to handle it? It is the sender, who will receive the feedback, not the other receivers. Or should it send another notification to everybody to disregard the previous notification? If so, wouldn't it be too late?

Comment: Maybe you could try to send upstream messages on Android. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream